# problems with sudo mv file /non_existing_folder - file disappeared

Tags: unix, sudo, mv

I was trying to move a `RubyOnRails.txt` file into a `/RUBY` directory, so for some reason I typed:

`mv RubyOnRails.txt /Ruby"`

And I got this error: `mv: cannot move ‘Untitled Document’ to ‘/Ruby’: Permission denied`

Obviously, I typed: `sudo mv RubyOnRails.txt /Ruby`

And then, I understood my error, the folder wasn't `/Ruby`, was `/RUBY`.

Now the file is gone, and I can't find it anywhere.

There is some way to find it or recover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file isn't gone, it's just renamed to `Ruby` and it's in root directory of your system `/`

You can still move it where you want like that `sudo mv /Ruby your_destination`

Comment: Thanks! You are right!, the problem is that I did the same thing 3 times. So the first one, I moved the file and renamed it, the second one I override it, and the third one it was override again. And now I loss all my work :'(

Comment: It will be hard, if at all possible. I have no experience with that. Here are 2 links about recovering overwritten file.  http://superuser.com/questions/446277/how-to-recover-a-file-overwritten-with-another-in-linux   http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149342/can-overwritten-files-be-recovered